# Breadcrumbs based on list of nested objects

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with logic on how to make dynamic breadcrumbs.
I have nested array of objects, and when a user clicks a folder, it adds to the breadcrumbs.

However, currently clicking 2 folders in the same folder adds both folders to the breadcrumbs rather than adding the last clicked folder.

Furthermore, clicking a folder thats deep within the folder tree will not show all previous folders it has passed.

All in all, I just need the logic for breadcrumbs, in javascript.

My attempt is as follows:

**Folders.json**

```json
[
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Quarterly Results"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Favourites",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Brawl Stars",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "NS dying in 5 seconds"
            },
            {
              "name": "Josiah raping NS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Coding",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "Coding is so fun"
            },
            {
              "name": "I love svelte",
              "files": [
                {
                  "name": "REPL"
                },
                {
                  "name": "oh nooo"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Knowledge Base 1"
    }
  ]
```

Sidebar.svelte

```html
<script>
export let currentFolder
    export let currentFolderFlow
    export let expanded = false;
    export let name;
    export let files;

const sideBarFolder = (folderName) => {
        if (currentFolder === folderName) {
            return false
        }

        currentFolder = folderName

        if (!currentFolderFlow.includes(folderName)) {
        currentFolderFlow = [...currentFolderFlow, folderName]
        } else {
            currentFolderFlow = currentFolderFlow.filter(i => currentFolderFlow.indexOf(i) <= currentFolderFlow.indexOf(folderName))
        }
    }
</script>

<button class=" pl-1" on:click={() => sideBarFolder(name)}>{name}</button>
```

**Main**

```html
<script>
import TreeView from './side-bar.svelte'
let currentFolderFlow = ['Knowledge Base']
let currentFolder = 'Knowledge Base'
</script>

<!-- Breadcrumbs -->
<div class="flex-1 px-3">
    <div class="text-md breadcrumbs border rounded-lg p-3">
        <ul id="breadcrumbs">
            {#each currentFolderFlow as folderFlow}
                <li>{folderFlow}</li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a folder name is not enough, for sure. e.g. if you have structure like `abc / def / abc`, you are in folder `def` and click on its child `abc`, it will crop to the root `abc` folder.

There are different ways to solve it.

1. Create some kind of unique ID for each folder and pass it. Thus, you'll have to scan for it each time, which will take much time.
2. Have a `parent` property in each folder, which will link to the parent object. And pass the folder object instead of its name.
3. You can pass an array of names: `sideBarFolder(["Favourites", "Coding", "I love svelte"])`. But to get the array, you'll have to use method 1 or 2 anyway, probably.